# Can I use chat to collaborate on an open source project?

Tags: discussion, chat

A few of us in the C# chat room came up with an idea for an open source project that we're going to work on.  Since the idea was sparked in chat, it seems fitting that we collaborate in chat.

The faq for chat says

> discussion should more or less revolve around the same topics you'd find at Stack Overflow

I think this is kind of a grey area.  People don't collaborate on projects in Stack Overflow, but chat is a different beast.

I want to move the conversation to its own room, but I want to make sure this use of the chat site is okay first.

Comment: Trust me, it's *a lot* better than what chat is normally used for here.  Have at it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Open Source... Gardening? Homebrewing? Yeah, that's *right out* - better take it to chat.se.

Open Source *programming*? Sounds fairly on-topic to me.